# Angular Firebase Authenticated Requests

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am saving form submissions to **Google Firebase Cloud Firestore** in test mode.

How can I do this securely? I don't want my users to have to authenticate via GitHub or something similar but still authenticate my application in some way.

I couldn't find anything regarding this online. Surely I am missing something here, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require some form of authentication using Firebase Authentication, then what you're doing now will never be truly "secure" by any definition of that word.  Since you haven't really said what your security requirements actually are, it's hard to give specific guidance.  But once you are using Firebase Auth, you can write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to make sure that a user can only write documents according to those rules.

Comment: Let's say I want to have a signup form for some contest. I want people to sign up for this contest via a form. Why would I want to have the user authenticate in this manner? I can get on board with a Captcha, but why would I make them sign in with OAuth for a form submission?

Comment: Because, as I said, Firebase Auth is the only way to control access to the database.  You really have no other options, unless you want to write backend middleware to handle the writes in a way that you feel is "secure".  To be perfectly clear: If you have nothing on your backend that ensures the security of the database access (either code or security rules), using whatever criteria you define as "secure", then your database is essentially open to unlimited reading and writing to the entire world.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Doug! So essentially, there is no way around having a backend that implements the Firebase Admin SDK and handles all the requests, correct?

Comment: If you're not using Firebase Auth with security rules, then you have no other way to control what happens with the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are anonymous users for firebase. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth